# Java OutputStream to Multiple files

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have an OutputStream, and I'd like to (on a conceptual level) broadcast it to multiple files. So for instance, if a byte shows up in the stream, I want that to get written to files A, B, and C.

How can I accomplish this using only one stream? Preferably with a pure Java solution.

Comment: It would be pretty trivial to write an implementation of OutputStream which proxied a list of OutputStreams and forwarded any calls to each one in turn.

Comment: I am confused: You write bytes to an OutputStream, not read them. So do you actually have an InputStream? If not, where are your bytes coming from?

Comment: @Joe Oh, there it is, I couldn't find my own stupid answer; thanks.

Comment: Oh snap, you guys are right. I looked all over but didn't see that one. What's the process now, do I delete this question since it's duplicate?

Answer (score 6):

You can use Apache Commons IO [TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) for this purpose.
This OutputStream proxies all bytes written to it to two underlying OutputStreams.
You can use multiple `TeeOutputStreams` in a chain when you want to write to more than two OutputStreams at once.

```java
OutputStream out = new TeeOutputStream(
  new FileOutputStream(new File("A")), 
  new TeeOutputStream(
      new FileOutputStream(new File("B")), 
      new FileOutputStream(new File("C"))
  )
);
```

Comment: flawless answer Fabian! Will surely check out TeeOutputStream.

Comment: Why isn't something like that in the standard library?